# Ordered Many-Many Relationship in Doctrine?

Tags: sorting, symfony1, doctrine, many-to-many

Attempting to link `Categories` to `Websites`, using `WebsiteCategory` as the refClass.

`WebsiteCategory` has a column `rank`, which indicates the order in which the categories should be retrieved when you call `$website->getCategories()`

I'm stumped, didn't think this would be so difficult. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was not able to get doctrine to order the relationship natively (like Damien was suggesting) instead, added a getCategories() function to the model which runs the proper query and returns the result set.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported for Many to Many relationships, the bug report is linked below with a possible patch, although some comments indicate it was not working.  As already noted by OP, I think the solution is to override the getCategories() function.

http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-651

Answer (score 0):

You can add an orderBy param in your schema.yml:

```
Gallery:
  columns:
    title: string(255)
  relations:
    Images:
      local: id
      foreign: gallery_id
      foreignAlias: Gallery
      type: many
      orderBy: position DESC
```

You can put multi fields with a comma.

Comment: This works on Many-One relationships, but I was not able to get the same type of declaration to work with a Many-Many. Considering there are 4 places I could put the ordering (Local, RefClass-Local, RefClass-Foreign, Foreign) perhaps I'm just not defining it correctly...